# Нахождение численного минимума методом Фибоначи

Tags: c#, алгоритм, ооп

Мне нужно найти численный минимум функции методом Фибоначчи.

f(x) - g(x) -> min

Функция f(x) это полином n-степени. Значение функции g(x) задается набором точек. Для функции g(x) необходимо выполнить интерполяцию с использованием полиномов Лагранжа.

Код написал, но вот проблема.. Не правильное значение минимума дает. Где я ошибся? Вроде и интерполяция правильная, и метод Фибоначчи..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double a = -10;
        double b = 20;
        double epsilon = 0.00001;
        List<Point> g_points = new List<Point>() { new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 2), new Point(2, 3), new Point(3, 3) };

        LagrangePolynomial g = new LagrangePolynomial(g_points);
        Polynomial f = new Polynomial(new List<double>() { 1, 0, 2 }); // полином f(x) = x^2 + 2

        FunctionDifference diff = new FunctionDifference(f, g);

        FibonacciSearch fs = new FibonacciSearch(diff, a, b, epsilon);
        double min = fs.FindMinimum();
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum: " + min);
    }
}

public class FibonacciSearch
{
    private readonly double phi = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2; // определение золотого сечения
    private IFunction function;
    private double a, b, epsilon;

    public FibonacciSearch(IFunction function, double a, double b, double epsilon)
    {
        this.function = function;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.epsilon = epsilon;
    }

    public double FindMinimum()
    {
        double x1, x2;
        while (Math.Abs(b - a) > epsilon)
        {
            x1 = b - (b - a) / phi;
            x2 = a + (b - a) / phi;
            if (function.Value(x1) >= function.Value(x2))
                a = x1;
            else
                b = x2;
        }
        return (a + b) / 2;
    }
}

public interface IFunction
{
    double Value(double x);
}

public class FunctionDifference : IFunction
{
    private IFunction f, g;

    public FunctionDifference(IFunction f, IFunction g)
    {
        this.f = f;
        this.g = g;
    }

    public double Value(double x)
    {
        return f.Value(x) - g.Value(x);
    }
}

public class Polynomial : IFunction
{
    private List<double> coefficients;

    public Polynomial(List<double> coefficients)
    {
        this.coefficients = coefficients;
    }

    public double Value(double x)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.Count; i++)
        {
            result += coefficients[i] * Math.Pow(x, i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class LagrangePolynomial : IFunction
{
    private List<Point> points;

    public LagrangePolynomial(List<Point> points)
    {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public double Value(double x)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.points.Count; i++)
        {
            double basicsPol = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < this.points.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j != i)
                    basicsPol *= (x - this.points[j].X) / (this.points[i].X - this.points[j].X);
            }
            result += basicsPol * this.points[i].Y;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как проверяете код? Как именно вы поняли, что этот код не работает? Что на входе? Что на выходе? Что должно быть?

Comment: Что вам не нравится в ответе? Я не нашёл в нём ошибки. В реализации есть микронедочёт, но ответ верный.